# What is the actual app binary limit in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When I deploy an app on my Go standard environment, the below size limit error occurred:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: App binary too big: 69351840 > 67108864
```

`67108864` is `64MB`. But this limit is different with what [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) says. The limit in the documentation is `32MB` instead:

> Each file is limited to a maximum size of 32 megabytes.

Is the documentation outdated? Or only Go has a higher limit than other languages? I want to find the documentation of actual app binary limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Go has a higher max static data file size limit than other languages. This change is not in the documentation and it needs to be updated to reflect the correct value for Go.

I've filed a public issue about it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112061972) for the documentation update.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is the reason, why only Go has a higher limit, that GAE Go doesn't support dynamic linking?

Comment: @HeungsubLee Thank you too! About your question, the GCP team received reports of users hitting the size limit when using Go. After looking into it, they considered appropriate to rise it.